# Are there any quests for the Eight/Nine Divines?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've completed Meridia's mission, and received dawn breaker (EDIT: oh, I would have never done this if I realized she was a Daedra!) :(

I also completed the Sybil of Dibella mission and became an Agent of Dibella.

I would like to know if there are any more *Aedric* quests in the game, I cannot play the Daedric quests with my current character who is rather straight-up and conscientious...

Comment: To the person who edited my post (yx?): I did mean AEDRIC quests, not DAEDRIC quests. I re-edited my post.

Comment: Daedroth is a specific type of Daedra. Meridia is not one, though she is a Daedra. It's a titch confusing.

Comment: I've adjusted the title to be more comprehensive - Aedra is technically correct, but you're likely to engender confusion if you insist on using that term.

Comment: my bad, you mentioned meridia, who's definitely not a divine so

Comment: @adityamenon Although Meridia is a Daedra, she's unambiguously allied with the living against the undead. That would make her "good" unless you have a soft spot for the rights of zombies.

Comment: @Bryan What do we want? BRAINS! When do we want it? BRAINS!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**AEDRA**

Unlike the Daedra, these don't have an organized each-prince-has-a-quest-and-good-reward
format. But they do exist, although we'll have to define them more loosely:

[Dibella](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Heart_of_Dibella)
[Kynareth](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Blessings_of_Nature) - Weak albeit unique reward. Unless you like saving trees. A lot.
[Mara](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Book_of_Love)

AFAICT the following have no proper quests:

Akatosh
Arkay (aside from a minor fetch quest in Whiterun that nets you a pittance in gold)
Julianos
Stendarr (But since the Vigilants of Stendarr are out and hunting werewolves, it's entirely possible in DLC. They have a lodge in Dawnstar.)
Talos (well, aside from fighting the Thalmor at every turn)
Zenithar

---

**DAEDRA**

There are some Daedric quests that might be fine for your paragon of morality to still do. I'll try to avoid spoilers, but here are the Daedric Quests by prince and evilness:

**Probably fine:**
[Azura](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Black_Star) - Just some necromancer hunting
[Clavicus Vile](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Daedra%27s_Best_Friend) - Just don't do *everything* Clavicus says
[Malacath](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Cursed_Tribe) - You ultimately help the Orcs
[Meridia](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Break_of_Dawn) - Pretty much the definition of Lawful Good
[Nocturnal](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Darkness_Returns) - Part of the Thieves Guild questline
[Sheogorath](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Mind_of_Madness) - You "help" Pelagius have some self-confidence

**Ambiguous:**
[Mehrunes Dagon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pieces_of_the_Past) - If you wait too long instead of following Dagon's command to kill someone, that person will attack you, which still satisfies Dagon. But it *is* Dagon.
[Mephala](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Whispering_Door) - The quest is fine, but the reward is only marginally useful if you're averse to killing friends
[Vaermina](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Waking_Nightmare) - Good only if you let the staff be destroyed, which means no reward

**Questionable:**
[Hircine](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ill_Met_By_Moonlight) - Werewolf hunting
[Sanguine](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:A_Night_To_Remember) - Drinking games, although you do fix all the mayhem you cause

**Evil:**
[Boethiah](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Boethiah%27s_Calling) - Murder
[Hermaeus Mora](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane) - But seriously, he's trying to get to the [Heart of Lorkhan](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Heart_of_Lorkhan)? Also, if you don't like elves this switches to the Good category.
[Molag Bal](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_House_of_Horrors) - Torture
[Namira](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Taste_of_Death) - Cannibalism
[Peryite](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Only_Cure) - You inhale hallucinogens then wipe out a den of his followers

Comment: I think the Sanguine Rose (the reward for the `Sanguine` quest) is one of the best (if not the best) secondary weapon in the game if you're an archer..  You spawn a leveled dremora, let them tank for you, and you can just hang out and kill everything from a distance.

Comment: Excellent answer! But I did not know Meridia was a Daedra? Ow! Did I just help a Daedra? Now my "Prowd Nord" will have to commit suicide :P

Comment: By the way Bryan, if you could please edit your post to include AEDRIC quests, I will accept it...

Comment: @adityamenon Added

Comment: Accepted the answer, thanks! But Kynareth is not a generous Aedra is she? No permanent unique rewards :(

Comment: @adityamenon Yeah, I edited that fact in. Nettlebane _is_ in fact unique -- and it absorbs magicka and is Ebony, so it's decent -- but it's nothing like the other two. You also get a nicer looking tree in the middle of Whiterun, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 4):

There is 1 [daedric quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Daedric_Quests) for every [daedric prince](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Daedric_Princes) with the sole exception of Jyggalag.  So in total there are 16 daedric quests.  Every quest will involve the daedric artifact of that prince in some way.

Comment: Jyggalag is a bit of a special snowflake anyway - until recently, he only appeared once every great time, so his only cultists were within the Shivering Isles themselves.

Comment: Azura's quest has a nice reward and is not really 'evil' for what its worth.

Comment: Definitely James, but you see my character is a typical Nord who just blindly follows stereotypes. He does not have the ability to make judgement of his own, just believes that all filthy Daedra are evil, and to Oblivion with the lot of them! :)

Answer (score 4):

There are only two quests for the Divines (Technically "Aedra", but they are always referred to as "Divines" in dialog):

[The Heart of Dibella](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Heart_of_Dibella)

and

[The Book of Love (Mara)](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Book_of_Love)

The other six (+1) Divines do not have associated quests in the base game.

Comment: @adityamenon - I chose not to include it because it's a quest for Kynareth's priest, not for *Kynareth*.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well R, Bryan put a great deal of work in his answer... I hope you don't mind me accepting that answer? You are the top performer anyway :)

Comment: @adityamenon Nope. No problems at all. I was surprised to get it in the first place, after Bryan updated his answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

What about Kynes token (Kyne is Kynareth). A man named Fjolti who lives in the south near Autumn Watch Tower will send you to kill spirit guardians and you receive a necklace that looks like the Gaulder Amulet.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what you class as aedra, according to the wiki staff of magnus classes as a aedric artifact http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Aedric_Artifacts so doing mages story would count out as helping a aedra. Also a good reward. Depending if you have dawnguard auriel is the elvish version of akatosh (Same person according to lore) getting his bow and saving the world would count as helping a aedra. Also good reward. Then there is Kyne/Kynareth's Sacred Trials with a honestly crap reward. Now there is The Heart of Dibella but the reward is again crap. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

the Gildergreen sapling also could count as an Aedric quest because of the the association of the tree in Whiterun with Kynareth. It is a priestess of Kynareth who gives out the quest.

And, of course, siding with the Stormcloaks helps out that ol' ninth divine, Mr. Talos.